# Spring Redirect POST to external link with Form Data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, multipartform-data

I have an external service address outside my Spring-MVC application where to submit this type of request shown below.

```
<form action="http://external.address.com/show.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' name='inst_id' value='102'>
    <input type='text' name='student_id' value='2305014'>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

And the link `(http://external.address.com/show.php)` show another view/html page in browser.

How can I make this request with form-data and post/redirect it form my spring controller of my native application.